# Table Join Distinct Field

Tags: vb.net, join, subquery, distinct

The problem which I am having is joining two tables. One table contains all the generic data and the second table contains old fields which have been given specific values. The exemplary tables below should help to clarify my setup.

### Table 1 (Generic Data)

```
ParaIndex   ParaName    ParaDefault
1           Cat         15
2           Fish        8
3           Dog         3
```

### Table 2 (Specific Data)

```
Project    ParaIndex   ParaValue
John       1           6
John       2           7
Alan       3           9
```

The goal then is to join these tables to get a single table:

### Table 3 (Table Join on ParaIndex for 'John')

```
ParaName   ParaIndex   ParaValue  ParaDefault
Cat        1           6          15
Fish       2           7          8
Dog        3                      3
```

So Table 3 would return all rows from Table 1 but would only show values for ParaValue where they are not empty. E What I have tried so far is a combination of changing the join type, distinct select, group by, select subqueries, and suggestions mentioned in other posts.

The end goal is then to use this query in vb.net as par of a form.

The closest which I have gotten is to return the requested data in table 3, but it would exclude rows which are not requested (e.g. if the query is for 'John' it would then exclude the parameters marked by 'Alan' which is 3-Dog in this case).

```
SELECT t1.ParaName, t1.ParaIndex, t2.ParaValue, t1.ParaDefault
FROM Table1 AS t1LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 AS t2
ON t1.ParaIndex = t2.ParaIndex
WHERE (((t2.ParaIndex) is null) OR t2.Project = 'John')
```

Comment: Show what you've tried.

Comment: Here is one of the queries which I have tried to get working.  

    SELECT  Table1.ParaIndex, Table1.ParaName, Table1.ParaDefault, Table2.ParaValue  
    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Table1.ParaIndex, Table1.ParaName, Table1.ParaDefault, Table2.ParaValue FROM Table1 LEFT JOIN Table2 ON Table1.ParaIndex = Table2.ParaIndex)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`:

```
SELECT t1.ParaName,
       t1.ParaIndex,
       COALESCE(CAST(t2.ParaValue AS VARCHAR(10), '') AS ParaValue,
       t1.ParaDefaule,
FROM dbo.Table1 t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Table2 t2
   ON t1.ParaIndex = t2.ParaIndex
WHERE t2.Project = 'John'
ORDER BY t1.ParaIndex
```

Comment: (excuse the formatting, having a hard time with it) I tried the code which you had proposed (had to adapt it for Access) but it still only returns the list of from t2 with data from t1. Whereas, I want to get all the fields from t1 (excluding the fields already in t2) and t2 for 'John'. The code which I have used is:
    SELECT t2.Project, t1.ParameterParaName, t1.ParaIndex, Nz(t2.ParaValue, Null) AS ParaValue, t1.ParaDefault 
    FROM dbo.Table1 t1 INNERLEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Table2 t2 ON t1.ParaIndex = t2.ParaIndex 
    WHERE t2.Project = 'John' 
    ORDER BY t1.ParaIndex